# Firebase Javascript / Typescript map compatibility

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I try to write a map to firebase I run into this error:

```
FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom Map object (found in field documentData.elements)
```

I want to write maps instead of arrays to firebase to be able to merge datasets without overwriting the whole array but only adding or removing entries of the map.
However, I can't get the map working, even if the firebase documentation says it's supporting maps.

My interface looks like this:

```
export interface Element {
   uid:string;
   value:string;
}
export interface DocumentData {
    uid: string;
    elements: Map<string, Element>;
}
```

Writing those as a document does not work and fails with the error above.

```
let documentData = {uid:"test_uid", elements: new Map([{"one", "test_string"}],[{"two", "test_string"}]]);
...
...
            .doc(documentData.uid)
            .set({documentData, {merge: true});
```

Does anybody have an idea how to write the map to the storage please? Is it actually an issue with the map or am I using set wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firestore only accepts plain old JavaScript objects that contain the fields and values to write to the document.  It doesn't accept an ES6 Map object, which is very much not the same thing.

Simply build the object and pass it to `set()`:

```
const data = {
    uid: "test_uid",
    elements: {
        one: "test_string",
        two, "test_string"
    }
}

set(data, {merge: true})
```

I suggest consulting the [documentation](http://And%20pass%20it%20to%20set():) for more examples.  Map objects are supported for Java, but not for JavaScript.

What will happen with the above code is it will update two fields, an "elements" will be a Firestore map type field.

Answer (score 0):

I created a method which writes a map to a flat object and adds a field that this member is a map so when fetching it from firebase it can be put back into the original object which works very well so far.

```
export function toFlatObject(data: any) {
    if (!data) {
        return null;
    }

    const obj: any = {};
    for (const [dataKey, dataValue] of Object.entries(data)) {
        if (dataValue instanceof Map) {
            const mapObj: any = {};
            dataValue.forEach((value, key) => {
                Object.defineProperty(mapObj, key.toString(), {
                    value: interfaceDataToFlatObject(value),
                    writable: true,
                    enumerable: true,
                });
            });
            Object.defineProperty(mapObj, "dataStructureIsMap", {
                value: true,
                writable: true,
                enumerable: true,
            });
            Object.defineProperty(obj, dataKey.toString(), {
                value: mapObj,
                writable: true,
                enumerable: true,
            });
        } else if (dataValue instanceof Object) {
            Object.defineProperty(obj, dataKey, {
                value: interfaceDataToFlatObject(dataValue),
                writable: true,
                enumerable: true,
            });
        } else {
            Object.defineProperty(obj, dataKey, {
                value: dataValue,
                writable: true,
                enumerable: true,
            });
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late with a solution but I developed one that works very well and wanted to share.

Initially, I found [this GIT repository](https://github.com/ClickSimply/typescript-map) while searching for something unrelated and it worked well but there are a number of issues with the implementation (see issues list).  In the end I created a new solution by extending the Map() class and borrowing a bit of code from the above GIT.

```
   class MyMap<K, V> extends Map<K, V> {
        
        /**
         * Outputs the contents of the map to a JSON object
         * 
         * @returns {{[key: string]: V}} 
         * @memberof MyMap
         */
        public toJSON(): { [key: string]: V } {
            const obj = {}
    
            const getValue = (value: any): any => {
                if (value instanceof MyMap) {
                    return value.toJSON()
                } else if (Array.isArray(value)) {
                    return value.map(v => getValue(v))
                } else {
                    return value
                }
            }
    
            for (const [key, value] of this) {
                obj[String(key)] = getValue(value)
            }
            return obj
        }
    }
```

A a test I ran the following successfully against a Firestore document:

```
// Instance
const mapTerms= new MyMap<string, string>()

// Add some items (I had this within a loop)
mapTerms.set(doc.id, doc.data().text)

// Write is as a map object into Firestore
await db.doc(<my doc path>).set({
    text: currentTermsOfUse,
    map: mapTerms.toJSON()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store map structure using custom type without using the es6 map.
Check the following Elements type

```js
export type Element = {
  key: string
  name: string;
  type: string;
}
export type Elements = { [key: string]: Element }

// To add element in the elements
const element: Element = {
  key: 'key1',
  name: 'myName',
  type: 'myType',
}
const elements = { [`${element.key}`]: element };

// To access an element in the elements using key
const element1 = elements['key1'];

// To access the first element in the elemenets
const element2 = elements[Object.keys(elements)[0]];

// store
app.firestore().collection('a').add(elements);
// or
app.firestore().collection('a').doc('doc').set(elements, merge: true);
```